# Using ninject to inject repository to winform error

Tags: c#, winforms, repository, ninject

I am using Ninject to inject my repository to my windows form .

So i install ninject from nuget .I add this to my window form :

```
 public class Binding: NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUserRepository>().To<IUserRepository>();
        }
    }
```

In my form i do this :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IUserRepository userRepository;
        [Inject]

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            userRepository = kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<User> saaa = userRepository.Get().ToList();
            int aaa = saaa.Count;
        }
    }
```

But i get this error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll

Additional information: Error activating IUserRepository using binding from IUserRepository to IUserRepository

No constructor was available to create an instance of the implementation type.



Activation path:

  1) Request for IUserRepository



Suggestions:

  1) Ensure that the implementation type has a public constructor.

  2) If you have implemented the Singleton pattern, use a binding with InSingletonScope() instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Bind<IUserRepository>().To<IUserRepository>();
```

This line is at least part of the problem; you aren't telling Ninject what *concrete* implementation of `IUserRepository` to use.

It's actually right there in the error message (emphasis mine)

> Additional information: Error activating IUserRepository using binding from **IUserRepository** to **IUserRepository**

Since you can't create an instance of an interface, you need to at least have one implementation of `IUserRepository` (e.g. `UserRepository`) and bind that to the interface:

```
 Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
```

Also, the `[Inject]` attribute is pointless in this case, since you're not injecting anything - you are creating the dependency directly from the container yourself (which is OK,although you can have proper injection, see [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html) for some ideas, which will also work for Ninject)

Comment: Thank you Stephen that was my problem

Comment: Good stuff; I've also updated the answer with a link that's worth reading as it will show you how to have proper injection possible whereby you can declare the IUserRepository in the Form's constructor, which is much neater :)